# Discord.js cannot read property 'content' of null

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

Hello guys i try to do command "warns" and i can't fix error can you help me please?
I know the problem is in "if(data.content.length)" and if i remove ".content.length" and use command the bot says "User has not warns" but i have.

Code:

```
const db = require('../warns')
const { Message, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js')

module.exports.run = async (_client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send('You don\'t have permissions to.')
    const user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
    if(!user) return message.channel.send('User not found.')
    const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    db.findOne({ guildid: message.guildid, user: user.user.id}, async(err, data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(data.content.length){
            var warny = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${user.user.tag} warns`)
            .setDescription(
                data.content.map(
                    (w, i) => 
                    `${i + 1}. | Moderator: ${message.guild.members.cache.get(w.moderator).user.tag}\nReason: ${w.reason}`
                    ))
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            message.channel.send(warny)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('User has not warns')
        }
    })
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'warns'
}
```

Error:

```
(node:5564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null
    at C:\Users\cyber\Desktop\CzikiBot\commands\warns.js:11:17
```

Comment: seems to be to do with your database, try looking at the structure in a viewer and make sure it is all set up correctly

Comment: The problem is your `data` is `null`. It does not find an entry in your database so it returns nothing. And that nothing does not have a property with the name `content`.